# Macchanger can't change wifi mac address in fedora25

Tags: linux, mac-address, fedora-25

When I type `macchanger -r wlp6s0`, it gives output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# macchanger -r wlp6s0

Current MAC:   ac:d1:b8:d8:77:c5 (unknown)

Permanent MAC: ac:d1:b8:d8:77:c5 (unknown)

[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system
```

I want to change my mac address at each login. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will get that message if WiFi is enabled.  Disabling WiFi will fix the problem.